# Cannot boot ISO of Guest OS on VMWare 17 for Linux [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: boot, uefi, vmware, vmware-workstation

I posted this on VMWare communities but I didn't get a reply.

---

I have an Asus PRIME Z690-P D4 (Intel 500 Chipset). This M/Board will not boot in UEFI with CSM when the onbboard video is used. This is because chipset does not support UEFI VBIOS graphic card, hence the integrated graphics mode does not support legacy boot and CSM option becomes non-configurable.

The host system is running Ubuntu 22.04.

I want to create a guest VM for Windows 11. I associate the CD with the ISO I downloaded from Microsoft.

[image: Setting CD to ISO]

When I run the VM (expecting it to boot off the ISO) nothing happens. As you can observe from the screenshot, the CD icon has an X on it.

Any idea how I could resolve this issue?

Thanks.

---

*Update on the topic*

I created a screen recording of the video creation process. The video is of the installation of Windows 7 (no TPM). it is at [VMWare 17 Linux not booting host OS to start installation](https://youtu.be/GNTzpIHyk9Y)

**Feel free to speed up the video - I still haven't found a replacement for Camtasia :-)**

I notice that there isn't the BIOS Boot screen. On my Windows machine this used to come up momentarily (I had extended it).

I am very new to having Ubuntu as my daily driver.

[image: CD not found]

Comment: My host OS is Ubuntu 22.04.  I am asking about VMWare for Linux software.  The Guest OS happens to be Windows.  My question is not related to Windows. It is about VMWare (running on Ubuntu) not able to boot off an ISO marked as a boot disk.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I'd suggest modifying your question then, to ensure it's on-topic.  My comment is the first mention of Ubuntu on this page, your question as worded mentions only Windows 11 (*a number of times*).

Comment: Done. Thanks for helping me improve the question.